# Regexp exec list of url's separated by coma ", *"

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i get a array of url's inside a string like :

```
"http://www.google.de, http://www.lycos.de, http://www.facebook.de"
```

Already tried this. This returns just the first coma. It should be reserved and global.

```
new RegExp(", *", "g").exec(attrValue);
```

Comment: Why not use `str.split()`?

Comment: Yes sure its a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) instead:

```
var origin = "http://www.google.de, http://www.lycos.de, http://www.facebook.de";
var urls   = origin.split(/,\s*/);
```

You don't have to use `new RegExp` construct, as JS has quite a [convenient notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for regex literals.

---

For the sake of completeness, here's how it can be done with `RegExp.match`:

```
var origin = "http://www.google.de, http://www.lycos.de, http://www.facebook.de";
var urls   = origin.match(/.+?(?=,\s*|$)/g);
```

The idea is essentially the same: for each pattern match iteration (as `/g` global modifier is used), we stop (using look-ahead subexpression) when either a sequence of comma and optional whitespace has been found, or when we reach the end of the string.

Comment: always got some trouble with this regex notation. don't know why. i'm a typescript user, but maybe its my fault.